# apache poi: can't re-open workbook: InvalidOperationException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, invalidoperationexception

I have a method to create and write an .xlsx file, which works fine:

```
public static void createFileAndwriteResult(String path) {
    f = new File(path);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Message.showMessage("", "Permission to result folder denied", false);

    }
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet resultSheet = wb.createSheet();
        //do stuff
        wb.write(fos);
        wb.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And another method to append stuff to that .xlsx:

```
public static void appendToFile() {
    File f = new File(path);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    Sheet resultSheet = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        try {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(f)); // <--- This is where the exception happens
            resultSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            //do stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

However, if I want to re-open that workbook, I get an InvalidOperationException saying: Can't open the specified file: 'PathToFile\file.xlsx'. The file exists in that folder. However the size is changed to 0kB when that exception happens. I tried different methods including:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(f);
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

and:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(f));
```

Any idea how to fix this / a way to reopen a workbook which was written / used before in the same program?

Comment: Although you close the workbook in the java program, you might have the excel process still running on your machine which would disallow another process thread to be started if you try to reopen the book. It might take a manual `taskkill /pid`

Comment: Have you tried WorkbookFactory? WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(f))

Comment: @andrucz yes tried that, same result...

Comment: @andrewdleach thanks didn't think of that, will give it a shot

Comment: @neza u r welcome. lemme know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fos = new FileOutputStream(f);` create an output stream with "append" option equals to false. So content is cleared.

You should define `true` to `append` argument:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
```

Comment: Excel binary files are not appendable, you have to overwrite them

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open a file to *read* that you already have opened to *write* - that's not going to work. Both times you reference File **f**

```
//You open an OUTPUT stream into File f here
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    try {
        //And here you try to read again
        wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(f));
```

You could create a new File for output and later replace the "old" input with the "new" output file.